# Receipt printing in Chrome - Bad quality

Tags: google-chrome, printing, receipt

When i try to print a receipt in Google Chrome the quality of the text is bad. (its dotted/rasterized) and to wide for the receipt.

I use Google Chrome 39.0.2171.71 m
With a Star TSP100 receipt printer with 80 mm receipt.

The receipt printer is as default set on 72xreceipt.
It does cut of at the right lenght.

The text looks dotted/rasterized ...
[image]

This is a problem within Chrome, because everything works fine in Firefox.
only my POS works faster on Chrome. Thats why i want to use chrome.

The print dialog says black-white printing.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: any luck to improve print quality. I have html+css based report having same bad quality on chrome

Comment: Nope. But we don’t use it anymore like this

Comment: any direction for alternative, how you are using now

Comment: We now use a pos system which does not use any browser. And the pos directly prints to the printer. Quality is Great now

Answer (score 9):

Set font "color:black" in your stylesheet, eg:

```
<style rel="stylesheet" media="print">
...
body {color:black;}
...
</style>
```

I had the exact same problem and this was the last thing that came to my mind and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome just supports graphics printing, this may cause some quality issues when dealing with receipt and text only printers.
Maybe changing font type and size helps a bit.
I've resolved this creating a native service that handles the printing logic since java applet is not supported now by default in Chrome.
Good luck.

Comment: Note, the native ESCP print services won't work with the TSP100 on non-Windows platforms unless using graphics.  This is a limitation of the TSP100 hardware.  The Windows driver is capable of interpreting ESCP commands and rasterizing them whereas the Mac and Linux drivers are not.

Comment: Also, for most thermal printers, the explanation in this article applies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38965573/3196753.  I'm not posting it as a solution here because the OP's problem is too specific for a broad solution.  I recommend the OP seeks help with Google Chrome (escalated via chromium developers) and Star driver support (escalated via Star support) as both products have developers which are experts on the rasterization techniques.  For printing via browser, this article applies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28783269/3196753