# How to print php page with html tags using qz print?

Tags: php, html, printing

I have a `php` page with html tags

```
<?php
$arr_bill_rows =  count($sale_item);
?>

<html lang="en">

        <head>
            <title>Invoice Print</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <style type="text/css">
 body   {font-family:Arial,sans-serif; margin:0px; padding:0px ; font-size:12px;} 
                 address { width: 200px; height:auto; float:right; font-size:12px; font-style:normal; margin:15px 0 0 0; text-align:right;}
                .page   { width:320px; background-color:#FFF; margin: 0px auto; overflow:hidden; padding:5px 10px; display: none; height: <?php echo (10 + ($arr_bill_rows * 0.5)); ?>cm; }  
                .header { width:100%; height:80px; float:left;}
                .header h1, .header p { margin:0; font-size: 14px; }
        .header h2 { margin:0px 0 15px; font-size: 18px}
                 .header h1 { margin:0; font-size: 20px;   text-align:center}   
                .text-left { text-align:left;}
                .text-right { text-align:right;}
                .text-center { text-align:center}

                .logo   { /* width:100px; height: 60px; */ float:left  }  
                .logo img   { width:100%; } 
                .heading    { width:100%; height:18px; float:left;  font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; margin:5px 0 5px 0; line-height:18px;}
                .name       { width:100%; height:19px; float:left; border-bottom:1px #ddd dashed; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;  }
                .footer     { width:100%; height:auto; float:left; border-top:1px #ddd dashed; text-align:right; margin:5px 0 0 0; line-height:25px; position:relative; bottom:0;}
                .inv-row    { width:100%; height:15px; float:left; font-size:12px; }
                .inv-box    { width:75px; height:15px; float:left;margin:5px 0 0 0;  }
                .content-box-out{ width:100%; float:left; }
                .content-box{ width:100%;  float:left;margin:25px 0 0 0;  }
                .content-box td{ height:23px;}
                .total { border-bottom:1px solid #999;}

                .content-box td { font-size:14px;}

                @media print {@page { margin: 0; padding: 0; visibility: hidden;  }.page{ display: block; } .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always;}}            
                @media screen{
                     body { background: #fff; margin:0px; padding:0px ;  } 
                     .page:nth-child(1){ display: block; margin: 0 auto 0 auto; border:1px #ddd solid; -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 5px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2); box-shadow: 2px 5px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2); } 
                } 


            </style>
<!--        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>-->
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="<?php echo $this->get_base_url(); ?>assets/lib/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="<?php echo $this->get_base_url(); ?>assets/lib/jquery/jquery-barcode.js"></script>


        </head>
        <body onLoad="">

            <!--Page -->
            <div class="page" id="invoice-print">

                <div class="header">
                    <h1 class="text-center"><?php echo INVOICE_HEAD ; ?></h1>
                    <p class="text-right"><?php echo INVOICE_ADDRESS1 ; ?> </p>
                    <p class="text-right"><?php echo INVOICE_ADDRESS2; ?></p>
                    <h2 class="text-center"><?php echo INVOICE_HEAD2 ; ?></h2>
                    <br/><br/>
        </div>
<!--                <div class="heading">INVOICE</div>-->


                <div class="name"><?php echo strtoupper($customer_name); ?></div>

                <div class="inv-row">
                    <div class="inv-box"> <?php echo $sale_invoice_no; ?></div>
                    <div class="inv-box" style=" width:180px; float:right">Date : <?php echo $inovice_date; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="content-box-out" style="position: relative; min-height: 70%">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="content-box">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-bottom:1px dashed #e3e3e3;"  width="5%">#</td>
                            <td style="border-bottom:1px dashed #e3e3e3;"  width="50%">Items </td>
                            <td style="border-bottom:1px dashed #e3e3e3;"  width="5%"  align="center">Qty</td>
                            <td style="border-bottom:1px dashed #e3e3e3;"  width="20%"  align="right">Rate</td>
                            <td style="border-bottom:1px dashed #e3e3e3;"  width="20%"  align="right">Total</td>
                        </tr>

                        <?php
                        $i = 1;$grosstotal = 0;
                       foreach ($sale_item as $row):
                        ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="3%"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->product_name; ?> </td>
                                <td width="5%" class="pull-left" align="left"><?php echo $row->sale_item_qty; ?></td>
                                <td class="pull-right" align="right"><?php echo round($row->sale_item_amount,2); ?></td>
                                <td class="pull-right" align="right"><?php echo (round($row->sale_item_qty*$row->sale_item_amount,2)); ?></td>
                            </tr>

                        <?php
                        //$grosstotal += round(($row->sale_item_qty*$row->sale_item_amount),2);
                        $i ++;
                        endforeach;

                        ?>                       

                    </table>
                    <div class="footer" > 
                       <?php if($sale_service_charge>0 || $sale_discount_total>0 || $sale_other_amount>0) :?>
                       <div class="pull-right">Net Total : <?php echo number_format($sale_invoice_total, 2);?></div> 
                       <?php endif;?>
                       <?php if($sale_service_charge>0) :?>
                       <div class="pull-right">Service Charge :<?php echo number_format($sale_service_charge,2);?></div>
                        <?php endif; if($sale_discount_total>0) :?>
                        <div class="pull-right">Discount : <?php echo number_format($sale_discount_total,2);?></div>
                        <?php endif; if($sale_other_amount>0) :?>
                        <div class="pull-right">Extra Charge : <?php echo number_format($sale_other_amount,2);?></div>
                          <?php endif;?>
                       <div class="pull-right total">Total :<?php echo number_format($sale_invoice_total_rounding, 2);?></div>
                    </div>


                </div>


            </div>  
            <!--Page End -->   
            <div class="page-break"></div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

I have to print this using `qz` print, how to do this? now I am using html print.

`Onclick` of print button

```
doprint_html('sales/print_invoice/" . $aRow->sale_id . "/duplicate-copy/')
```

calls and it do html print , but i ned to use qz

by changing

```
print_qz_invoice('sales/print_invoice/" . $aRow->sale_id . "/duplicate-copy/')
```

connection to `qz` was made.

```
 function print_qz_invoice(url){ 
   if($('#printer').val()!=''&&$('#printer_type').val()==1 ){ 
      var printer = $('#printer').val();  
                                    printer = printer.replace(/%20/g, " ");  
                                    findPrinter(printer);  

                                       window['qzDoneFinding'] = function() {  
                                        doprint_qz_sale21(url+'/'+$('#printer').val()+'/'+$('#printer_type').val()+'/');  //,printer

                                       };
   }else{ 
        doprint_html(url);
   }
        }



  function doprint_qz_sale21(url){ 

        var base_url  = $("meta[name=baseurl]").attr("content");
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: base_url + url,
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
               alert("Unable process print please try again");
            },              
            beforeSend: function(){
              $("#print-page").html("");
            },                  
            success: function(json){ 
               // printEPL_barcode(json,show_price);
                dos_print_qzs(json);
            }
        });
    }
```

by ajax call i take all variables i nedd , and in qz.js

```
function dos_print_qzs(data) { 

    if (notReady()) { return; }
      $(json).each(function(index,data) { 
    qz.appendHTML(data.replace("<strong>","\x1B\x21\x38").replace("</strong>","\x1B\x21\x08")

    );
      });
    qz.printHTML();
}
```

But this is not works, is this is the correct method?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a mix of HTML and raw (ESC/POS) commands in your final `appendHTML` statement.  You need to choose one or the other.  This is covered in more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38965573/3196753

Furthermore, the HTML renderer in QZ Tray 1.9 was very limited and cannot handle the majority of the content.  This has since been vastly improved in QZ Tray 2.0 and higher.

```
var config = qz.configs.create("Printer Name");
var data = [{
  type: 'html',
  format: 'plain', // or 'file' if using a URL
  data: '<html><body><h1>Hello world</h1></body></html>'
}];
qz.print(config, data).catch(function(e) { console.error(e); });
```